# Can't update: no tracked branch

Tags: git, github, android-studio

I am on Android Studio (Preview) 0.6.0 on Windows and was trying to share my project on GitHub. I used Git Shell to initialize, add, commit and push the project to GitHub. But when I tried to update my project from within Android Studio [image], I got this error:

```
Can't update: no tracked branch
No tracked branch configured for branch master.
To make your branch track a remote branch call, for example,
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

It does provide this suggestion but I am not sure what to do at this point. Is there a way to fix this from within Android Studio?

Comment: The --set-upstream flag is deprecated and will be removed. Consider using --track or --set-upstream-to.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

So after reading a bit on how git sets up the repo. I realized that I ran the command

```
git push origin master
```

but instead for the first time I should have ran

```
git push -u origin master
```

which sets up the upstream initially. Way to go!

Comment: I hate git at times little switches like that are tedious and obtuse

Comment: You saved my time, everyday i meet this issue for a week

Comment: I've already used the second command. but still have the same message when trying to update from within Android-Studio !!

Comment: @Suda.nese Strange! That shouldn't be the case. Make sure you have included **-u** in the command else try re-launching the terminal and then launch git.

Comment: I am 100% confident that I used the syntax above. In fact, I started fresh just to make sure this work, but unfortunately I am still stuck in the same problem: can't update from within Android-Studio !!

Comment: If all else fails, ask yourself, "Did I cut and paste this, or type it manually?"

Answer (score 140):

If I'm not mislead, you just need to set your local branches to track their pairs in the origin server.

Using your command line, you can try

```
git checkout mybranch
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/mybranch
```

That will configure something as an equivalent of your local branch in the server. I'll bet that Android Studio is complaining about the lack of that.

If someone knows how to do this using the GUI of that IDE, that would be interesting to read. :)

Comment: Is there actually a way to do this directly in the Storm GUI ?

Comment: Do you refer to IntelliJ Web Storm? If so, I don't use that tool often enough to telll..

Comment: For any of the JetBrains IDEs; checkout the branch by clicking on the bottom right VCS tool then open the Terminal tool which will put you in the right directory - then type "git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/mybranch"

Comment: It's too helpful For me. Thank you So much and I gave you upvote. Woot Woot !

Comment: I had to do a "git fetch" before this

Comment: @Kong 's command saved my previously detached HEAD. Not it's again tracking correct branch and all. PHPStorm does not do a good job to help you with git, better learn it in a shell env.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem when I transferred the ownership of my repository to another user, at first I tried to use `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master master`  but the terminal complained so after a little bit of looking around I used the following commands
`git fetch`
`git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master master`
`git pull`
and everything worked again

Answer (score 12):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

Worked for me....where I have a single branch in my repo called master.  The response was "Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin."

Answer (score 7):

Create a new folder and run `git init` in it.

Then try `git remote add origin <your-repository-url>`.

Copy all the files in your project folder to the new folder, except the .git folder (it may be invisible).

Then you can push your code by doing:
 `git add --all`; or `git add -A`; 
`git commit -m "YOUR MESSAGE"`;
 `git push -u origin master`.

I think it will work!

Comment: I was able to push via Git Shell. I want to know how to update from within Android Studio. Please read the question.

Comment: That doesn't match up with the error message at all, those are just the steps to set up for the first time. That won't fix an error with no tracking branches.

Comment: Yess, thank you, it is a valid answer!

Answer (score 4):

In the same case this works for me:

```
< git checkout Branch_name
> Switched to branch 'Branch_name'

< git fetch
> [Branch_name]      Branch_name       -> origin/Branch_name

< git branch --set-upstream-to origin/Branch_name Branch_name
> Branch Branch_name set up to track remote branch <New_Branch> from origin.
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error but in PyCharm because I accidentally deleted my VCS origin. After re-adding my origin I ran:

```
git fetch
```

which reloaded all of my branches. I then clicked the button to update the project, and I was back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced The same problem So I used the **Git directly** to push the project to GitHub.

In your android studio

Go to VCS=>Git=> Push: use the Branch Name You Commit and hit **Push Button**

Note: tested for android studio version 3.3

Answer (score 3):

This isuse because of coflict merge. If you have new commit in origin and not get those files; also you have changed the local master branch files then you got this error. You should fetch again to a new directory and copy your files into that path. Finally, you should commit and push your changes.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have a local branch "Branch-200" (or other name) and server repository contains "origin/Branch-1". If you have local "Branch-1" not linked with "origin/Branch-1", rename it to "Branch-200".

In Android Studio checkout to "origin/Branch-1" creating a new local branch "Branch-1", then merge with you local branch "Branch-200".

Answer (score -1):

```
 git commit -m "first commit"

 git remote add origin <linkyourrepository>

 git push -u origin master
```

will works!