# GitLab: No tracked branch configured for branch master

Tags: git, android-studio, gitlab

I am trying to update my local reposity from within Android-Studio. I do this through:

VCS --> Update project , or by clicking:

[image]

But I keep getting the following balloon:

[image]

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24215286/2135363) answer, but still getting nowhere with the message above. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24215233/2135363) answer, yet no success.

Please help !

Comment: If you have git bash or whatever Windows thing is popular, then you can cd/navigate to your project directory in the shell and run the command it tells you at the bottom of that message.

Comment: you can find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215032/cant-update-no-tracked-branch

Comment: you can find your answer here
[Can't update: no tracked branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215032/cant-update-no-tracked-branch)