# Git pull doesn't work (Can't update: no tracked branch)

Tags: git, android-studio

I just tried git and managed to connect with the repository and to commit and push updates. I am also able to pull with VCS->Git->Pull, but the button to update the project (this one: [image: blue arrow showing downwards]
) does not work.

I get the message:

```
Can't update: no tracked branch

No tracked branch configured for branch develop in Git repository /Users/myname/Documents/Android Studio/Depanis/app/src/main/java/com/example/myname/depanis To make your branch track a remote branch call, for example, git branch --set-upstream-to origin/develop develop
```

I tried the recommended `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/develop develop` (this was also the solution in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215032/cant-update-no-tracked-branch)), but it did not work.

I have no idea why pushing works perfectly, but pulling just if I use the option in the menu.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you get when you when you type `git status`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't update: no tracked branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215032/cant-update-no-tracked-branch)

Comment: @antzshrek, I get: On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Answer (score 5):

Let me guess, when you are trying to run your git command command, you run this:

```
git pull
```

So instead of running just that, you should include the name of the branch you're tryna pull.

```
git pull origin <branch_name>
```

I hope this solve your issue.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to pull with a command, but with the button in the menu bar. (this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV6BM.png)

Comment: I'm lost on what you mean by you're tryna use the button. I thought the aim is to `pull` and `merge` new changes?

Comment: Yes it is. I am able to do so, if I use the command or the menu, but I'd like to use the button and this doesn't work

Comment: feel free to be clear on your question, SO community is very ready to help you solve your issue.

Comment: Thats helpful...but I am wondering why suddenly the pull option is not working from Android studio and

Comment: @akash89 what error message are you getting?